# The web site looks different with same resolution in different computers

Tags: display, resolution

**Hello!**
I’m designing web sites after a while and I’m looking for a new laptop. And I have noticed that web site can look different with the same screen resolution in different computers. Why is it so? I used the screen resolution 1366x768px with several different laptops running Windows 7 and with one new laptop tested web sites were more narrow. Is the reason pixel density I just read about from a blog - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2012/03/21/scaling-to-different-screens. Does it depends on how old the computer is,  which Windows is installed etc..

Is there any tool for testing web sites etc with different screen resolution if it should be pixel densitive.. I mean I can run it exmple on the big screen and I can decide how big (how many inch) my virtual screen is and how big the screen resolution is..

I was looking for 14“ laptop with 1600x900 screen resolution but the web sites looked different with 1366x768 resolution in that computer and in a other new 15.6“ computer. And I’m just confused..

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Screen size and traditional (4:3) vs wide screen (16:9) will make a big difference.  If you set the resolution at 1366x768 and that is not the native resolution it will either leave you with black boarders or stretch it to fill the screen.  All flat screen monitors have a native resolution and that is how many real pixels it has everything else is stretched bigger or smaller to emulate that resolution.

The version of windows makes no difference.

If one browser has a bunch of tools bars installed that also shrinks your useable area and can distort things.  A high pixel density just makes things smaller.

If the browser has been resize to a tiny part of the screen, the browser will twist and contort the content to make it fit.

Now if you force scroll bars on then it will render the content in the correct space, but the user will have to scroll left and right in addition to vertically.

Answer (score 0):

The way the website looks is determined in part by the browser - of particular notes, different browsers may have different sizes associated with various fonts (see [here](http://sbpoley.home.xs4all.nl/main/adjust.html)) as well as different installed fonts and ways of interpreting the HTML.

It would not be correct to assume that browsers all display things similarly, even where you specify as much as possible - the idea of HTML is to be able to be rendered as appropriate on any given device - if you need an exact look and feel, thats what PDF is all about.

Another pointer - the same colors can vary hugely in how it looks across monitors - and this is worth taking into consideration when designing.   (Its particularly noticeable on a laptop with a good display connected to a cheap large monitor for instance - identical window just moved across - or even same image mirrored on 2 monitors can look different).